# A generalization of Tietze's extension theorem

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I'm very interested in proving the following theorem because it is a generalization of Tietze's extension theorem.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a normal topological space, $A$ a closed subset of $X$, $f \in C(A)$ and $P$ and $Q$ equicontinuous non-empty subsets of $C(X)$. Suppose $p(x) \leq f(x) \leq q(x)$ for each $p\in P$ , $q \in Q$ and $x \in A$. 
If $r(x) = \sup\{p(x) \colon p \in P\} \leq \inf\{q(x) \colon q \in Q\} = s(x)$ por all $x \in X$, then there exists an extension $F \in C(X)$ of $f$ such that $p(x) \leq F(x) \leq q(x)$ for each $x \in X$ and each $p \in P $ and $q \in Q$.

**Note:** Something that worries me about this theorem is the existence of $r$ and $s$.

**My attempt**

The equicontinuity hypothesis implies that $r,s \in C(X)$. Let us define $g \colon A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = f(x)-r(x)$, since $g$ is continuous there is, (by Tietze's extension theorem), a map $G \in C(X)$ such that $G|_A = g$. Let us now define $h \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{equation}
h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{si} \hspace{0.3cm} G(x) < 0\\ s(x)-r(x) & \text{si} \hspace{0.3cm} s(x) -r(x) < G(x)\\ G(x) &  \text{si} \hspace{0.3cm} 0\leq G(x) \leq s(x)-r(x)\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I want to show that the function $F \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x) = h(x)+r(x)$ is the desired extension of $f$. But there are three things that I still haven't been able to do to finish:

**(1)**  I must guarantee that $h(x) \in C(X)$, that is, I must prove that $h(x)$ is continuous on $X$. How can I do that? I know that the functions $h_1(x) = 0$, $h_2(x) = s(x)-r(x)$ and $h_3(x) = G(x)$ are continuous in $X$, but I don't know if it is enough to say that $h $ is continuous on $X$.

**(2)** I must also show that $F(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$. If I fix $a \in A$, then $F(a) = h(a)+r(a)$ and I think $F(a)=f(a)$ if $h(a) = G(a)$, but this happens if $0 \leq G(a) \leq s(a)-r(a)$. Why would this happen if $a \in A$?

**(3)**  Finally, how can I deduce that $p(x) \leq F(x) \leq q(x)$ for all $x \in X$?

Any help is appreciated

Here are some definitions:

**Definition:** $C(X) = \{f \colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \;\vert\; f \hspace{0.2cm}\text{is continuous}\}$

**Definition:** A subset $S \subset C(X)$ is said to be equicontinuous at $x_0$ if given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a neighborhood $U_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ such that $|f(x) -f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ for each $x \in U_{x_0}$ and each $f \in S$. The subset $S$ is equicontinuous if it is equicontinuous at every point of $X$

Comment: If you know that $p(x) \leq f(x) \leq q(x)$ for all $p \in P, q \in Q, x \in A$ then $\sup_{p \in P} p(x) \leq \sup_{p \in P} f(x) = f(x) = \inf_{q \in Q} f(x) \leq \inf_{q \in Q} q(x)$ for all $x \in A$. So I think this additional assumption about $r$ and $s$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think the difference is that you have $r(x) \leq s(x)$ for $x \in A$ and my statement is for all $x \in X$. is it correct?

Comment: Oh I see! Apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Can you give me details about what remains for me to prove the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your solution. By Tietze's extension theorem, there exists a continuous  extension $F_0 \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $f$. Define, for all $x \in X$,
$$F_1(x):=\max\{r(x),F_0(x)\} \,$$
and
$$F(x):=\min\{s(x),F_1(x)\} \,.$$
Now maximum and minimum of continuous functions is continuous, so $F$ is the desired extension.